# How to add paginate in laravel with relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I need to paginate this where I need to find id but i don't know how.

```
    function customerContact($id)
{

    $customers = Customer::with('contacts')->find($id);

    return Inertia::render('Customers/Contacts/Index', [
        'customers' => $customers,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what "this" refers to here. When you do `find()` you only get one result so that cannot be paginated.

Comment: I have customer with many contacts and i want  table with all contacts from that customer with pagination.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$customers = Customer::find($id)->contacts()->paginate();
```

Answer (score 1):

on the third line in the customerContact() function

```
$customers = Customer::with('contacts')->find($id);
```

change to

```
$customers = Customer::find($id)->contacts()->paginate();
```